# How to hide a specific category posts in my monthly archive?

Tags: categories, archives

I am using the twenty eleven theme in my wordpress site.

In posts, I have two categories. One is blogs and other is News.

The monthly archive displays the posts of all categories while I want that the monthly archive should only display the posts of blogs category.

How will I do this?

I have also installed the wp_pagenavi plugin for the pagination.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two ways of doing it:

You can use a filter to alter the query when viewing an archive page. You will need to find the ID of your category 'blogs' (you can obtain it from the slug using [`get_term_by`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by)). Alternatively you can exclude a particular category by ID.

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_change_query'); 
    function my_change_query($query){
        if(is_archive()){
           $blog_term = get_term_by('slug', 'blogs', 'category');
           $blog_term_id = $blog_term->term_id;
           $query->set('cat', $blog_term_id);//Include category with ID $blog_term_id
           //$query->set('cat','-'.$blog_term_id);//Exclude category with ID  $blog_term_id
        }  
     return $query
    };
```

or, more commonly, you can alter the `archive.php` template file and insert the following just above the `if(have_posts())`.

```
global $wp_query;
$args = array_merge( $wp_query->query, array( 'category_name' => 'blogs' ) );
query_posts( $args );
```

See the Codex on [`query_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) and [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters).

Comment: I used the the 2nd solution and it worked. Thanks